# Project Euler 23 - No matter what I do, my answer is far too big

Tags: python

Problem 23 asks for the sum of all numbers "not the sum of two abundant numers". We need only check numbers smaller than 28123. An integer n is abundant if its proper divisors sum to an integer greater than n - 12 is the first abundant number since 1+2+3+4+6 = 16 > 12. This makes 24 the smallest number which is a sum of 2 abundant numbers, so we want to exclude it from the sum.

Here's my python code, which I've tried many variations of, but using the same idea:

```
import math

def divisors_of(n):
    divs=[1]
    for i in range(2,int(math.sqrt(n))+1):
        if i**2 == n:
            divs.append(i)
        elif n%i == 0:
            divs.append(i)
            divs.append(n//i)
    return divs

def is_abun(n):
    return sum(divisors_of(n))>n

numbers=[i for i in range(1,28123)]

for i in numbers:
    for j in range(1,i):
        if is_abun(j) and is_abun(i-j):
         numbers.remove(i)
         break

print(sum(numbers))
```

The idea is simply that if j and i-j are abundant numbers, then of course j + (i-j) = i is a sum of abundant numbers, so I remove it from my list of numbers. Then I sum over all remaining numbers. I don't see how this could possibly fail. However, the result should be (gotten from another source) 4179871, while I always get something in the ballpark of 197711987, which is over 47 times too large.

I really cannot understand how this fails to generate the correct result. There must be some line which isn't doing what I think it is, but everything here is just *too simple* for me to be suspicious of them. I thought the most likely error would be in calculating the abundant numbers, but I am almost completely sure that part's correct (if I get the code as is to generate a list of abundant numbers less than 28123, I get a list of length 6965, which is how many abundant numbers less than 28123 WolframAlpha claims).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are modifying the list `numbers` while you are iterating over it. This results in you removing less numbers than what you expect.

You should iterate over a copy of it:

```
for i in list(numbers):
    for j in range(1,i):
        if is_abun(j) and is_abun(i-j):
         numbers.remove(i)
         break
```

To understand what's happening consider this:

```
>>> numbers = list(range(10))
>>> for i in numbers:
...     if i%2 == 0:
...         numbers.remove(i)
...     print(i)
... 
0
2
4
6
8
```

As you can see the `for` loop only iterates over even numbers. That's because the `for` loop above is *roughly* equivalent to the following:

```
i = 0
while i < len(numbers):
    number = numbers[i]
    if number % 2 == 0:
        numbers.remove(number)
    print(number)
    i += 1
```

So the first time you have `i = 0` and thus `number = 0`, you remove the `0` from `numbers` so now you have `numbers = [1,2,3,4,..., 9]`. Note how the value `1` ended up in position `0`, so the next iteration we have `i = 1` and `numbers[1] == [1,2,3,4,...,9][1] == 2` so we have skipped the number `1`!

Everytime you remove a number the list is modified and if this modification leads to the items being shifted to the left you are effectively skipping them. That's why you want to iterate over a *copy* of the list: in this way the modifications to the original list do not affect the numbers "yielded" during iteration..

Comment: I've made the edit, and now my code is taking ages (it took about 5 seconds previously!) so we shall soon see if this was the only issue. I said I had tried many variations; one was numbers[i]=0 instead of numbers.remove(i). This wouldn't cause the shifting you mentioned, but I still had more or less the same output. Any idea what happened in that case?

Comment: @FireGarden Well, one simple way is to avoid re-computing abudant numbers. I mean: your code is calling `is_abun(1)` *a lot* of times, and same goes for `is_abun(2)`. A simple way to speed this up is to first compute the set of abundant numbers: `abundants = {i for i in range(1, 28123) if is_abun(i)}`, and then inside that loop replace `is_abun(j) and is_abun(i-j)` with just `j in abundants and (i-j) in abundants`.

Comment: @FireGarden Depending on how many numbers end up in this `abundants` set it might be faster to just compute all possible sums and remove this value from the Gaussian sum up to `n`.

Comment: Yeah, the first few attempts I first calculated a complete list of abundants, but I got rid of it looking for faults. I gradually made it less and less efficient to make it more and more explicit, It was a real pain haha. Though my code now produces the correct result, so thank you very much!